# Is there a specification available for the Autodesk SVF format?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, wavefront, dwg

I'm building a cross platform 3D viewing application in C#/C++ and would like to add support for Autodesk SVF files.

I looked at Autodesk Forge but it has limited support for exporting to open formats such as OBJ, and Autodesk SVF does not appear to be the same format as the similarly named Simple Vector Format (http://www.svf.org/) as was stated here: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/updated-little-more-detail-behind-autodesk-forge-apis-0

Is there a schema or specification available somewhere that details the structure of Autodesk's SVF format?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer: no there isn't as it's a proprietary format (that has been breached in some country already and legal actions were needed to resolve the issue...)

The long answer and please view this as my personal rambling w/o any real authority or credibility:

[image]

I'd recommend to stay tuned to the official Forge website and see if they'd choke up more info on SVF(aka the `Streaming Viewing Format`) for public knowledge.

Comment: Pretty sure SVF stands for `Simple Vector Format` not `Streaming Viewing Format`. Source: https://labs.blogs.com/its_alive_in_the_lab/2019/07/new-autodesk-forge-viewer-now-available.html