# design automation api: 3ds max svf import

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

im trying to use 3ds max design automation api to generate lightmap UVs and bake AO (using the flatiron plugin)
Few questions regarding that before I dive deep.

1. does max support svf import directly in max for the design automation api? (I know it supports svf export). I tried looking at the docs and this was not clear.
2. For the svf export option, does svf support a second set of UVs ? If there is a spec for this format that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: I would like to get more information on what you are trying to do.  I would not typically expect someone to try to import an SVF file into 3ds Max.  (These files are usually only used for 3d web display/preview)

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this can help.

1. 3ds Max does not support SVF import. Only export.
2. There is no public spec for the svf format as far as I know.  See this previous question/answer here: [Is there a specification available for the Autodesk SVF format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57889136/is-there-a-specification-available-for-the-autodesk-svf-format).

Note: I am not familiar with the flatiron plugin but it seems like a commercial plugin with its own licensing system. You might have a hard time repackaging the plugin to making it work on Design Automation because of the licensing.

If you aren't aware you might want to take a look at the new bakeToTexture feature that was introduced in 3dsMax 2021.
Here are some useful links about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2iZhmrNwwU&ab_channel=KemetCorporation

http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-B67A2495-89E4-464A-8913-35C957E950EB

http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-BC5AE8EA-A88C-4CF3-AF63-4C45FB48EEB5

Comment: this is very useful information and will work for my needs. Since the storage bucket will have the original unconverted file anyway, I will feed that into max. One question that remains unanswered, does SVF support a second UV set? I would like to bake AO to a second UV set and keep the first as for textures..etc..

Comment: Right now LMV only support one set of UVs as far as I can tell.  The 3ds Max svf exporter should pick which UV channel to use by looking at the Map Channel specified by the diffuse texture.

Comment: thats too bad SVF does not support a second UV set, which essentially makes using lightmap uvs with the SVF format impossible.